# How to add a looping selector to a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, loopingselector

I'm trying to a add a list of numbers like in the picture below to a page in a Windows Phone 8.1 app, but I can't find the looping selector control in the toolbox to acheive this:

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

I've tried to add the missing control by right clicking on the toolbox and adding a control but its not there.

This is how I've achieved picking a time using the coding4fun time span picker:

```
<c4fToolkit:TimeSpanPicker Header="Rest Interval" x:Name="restTimeSpanPkr" Max="12:59:59" Step="1:1:1" Margin="-12,323,12,-278" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to add the missing tool or is there a different way of achevingthis in Windows phone 8.1?

[image: toolbox missing looping selector]

[image: list of numbers]

Comment: Did you follow the article? "To begin using LoopinSelector first add a reference to  the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll  assembly which is installed with the toolkit and you can find it in ...". I don't use the toolbox personally so I'm not sure if custom components show up there. In general I wouldn't recommend using WP7 controls on 8.1 anyway, many of the styles will be missing or wrong.

Comment: @rikkit I've added the toolkit to the project and there is a reference in my references folder and also the apporpriate namespace has been added to my page's XAML , yet when I try to add a looping selector it still gives me the following `namespace prefix primitives is not defined` , any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Windows Phone Toolkit using NuGet or download it on their website: [The Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/)

If the toolkit is successfully installed the reference folder should look like this

[image]

Then add the Primitive namespace to the XAML file.

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:toolkit_primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
```

Then you can use the looping selector.

```XAML
<toolkit_primitives:LoopingSelector>
    <primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <!-- design your own square box+text -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>      
</toolkit_primitives:LoopingSelector>
```

---

Intellisense should pick it up as well

[image]

Comment: I tried the above, added the toolkit then added the namespace to the to the XAML file but I'm getting `the namespace prefix primitives is not defined` . Any idea as to whats up here? I seem to have followed all the relevant steps.

Comment: The references folder shows a reference to all the above so still not sure whats up.

Comment: @BrianJ Best to create a new project and follow the steps (just to make sure if you can get it working).  I added a few pictures to help you out.

Comment: Okay I've just tried the above and intellisense is picking up the looping selector but when I try to paste in your code I get the same error. Is the a way I can add a simple looping selector?

Comment: @BrianJ I think this will be too difficult to debug.  Here's the simplest demo project of LoopingSelector on my OneDrive that I can think of.   https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F2F16D176D29EFC!15189&authkey=!ACYDyasdYwAb-Lg&ithint=folder%2czip

Comment: @BrianJ Only default controls are "simple" to use.  Anything below and above them require time and effort.

Comment: Valid point, I'll have a look into the above link and see what I can come up with.

Comment: The **WPtoolkit** is not available for **WP8.1** at the moment and is only available for **WP8.0**. The question is for WP8.1. I don't know how @BrianJ accepted the answer. Chubosaurus, do you know any solution for WP8.1?

Comment: @JohnCroneh You can install the toolkit on WP8.1 Silverlight.  If he's using runtime, no where in the post did he said so.  If he was following that tutorial then I assume he was using Silverlight.